# throw an error when initialDueDate parameter is invalid javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

The function `calculateNextDueDate` given an `initialDueDate` and an `interval` returns the `nextDueDate`. I also need this function to be able to test the validity of the arguments being passed. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

```js
const INTERVAL = {
  monthly: moment.duration(1, 'months'),
  quarterly: moment.duration(3, 'months'),
  yearly: moment.duration(1, 'years')
}

function calculateNextDueDate(initialDueDate, intervalCode) {
  if (moment().diff(initialDueDate) < 0)
    return initialDueDate;
  return calculateNextDueDate(initialDueDate.add(INTERVAL[intervalCode]), intervalCode);
}


// usage
console.log(calculateNextDueDate(moment('2016-01-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'monthly').format('LL'))
console.log(calculateNextDueDate(moment('2016-01-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'quarterly').format('LL'))
console.log(calculateNextDueDate(moment('2016-01-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'yearly').format('LL'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @RobG is this better?Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Moment.js documentation for [*validation*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/), you need something like:

```
if (!moment(initialDueDate).isValid()) {
  throw new Error('Invalid date: ' + initialDueDate);
}
```

You don't say what *initialDueDate* is (Date? string?). If it's a string, you should also provide the [*format*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) of the string to the parser, otherwise you're relying on moment.js to guess the format. Also see the [*Parsing Guide*](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/).

```js
['2017-02-28',  // valid date
 '2017-02-29'   // invalid date
 ].forEach(function(initialDueDate) {
 
  if (!moment(initialDueDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD').isValid()) {
    throw new Error('Invalid date: \'' + initialDueDate + '\'');
 
 } else {
    console.log(initialDueDate + ' is valid');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```